# ASP.NET MVC - Controller receives the list incorret from view using Html.BeginForm()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get multiple instances of my model objects sent to the controller as a list but for some reason, the count of the list is always 1 and the value of the object is always 0 so nothing is actually posted when submit is pressed.

This is my View:

```
@model List<MVCModel.Models.Student>

 <b>Items</b>    @ViewBag.Items <br />
 <b>Value</b>    @ViewBag.Value <br />
  
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tbody id="GenaratorList">
        <tr>
          @{
            int counter = 0;
            <td>Enter Name: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter].Name, new {id = "Name"})</td>
            <td>Enter Age: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter].Age, new {id = "Age"})</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addGenarator()" /></td>
        </tr>
        counter++;
        }
     <tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
}

<script>
    count = 0;
    function addGenarator() {
        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Age = $('#Age').val();
        var Student = "studentModels[" + count + "]";
        $('#GenaratorList').append('<tr><td><input id="' + Student + '.Name" Name="' + Student + '.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Name + '"></td><td><input id="' + Student + '.Age" Age="' + Student + '.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Age + '"></td></tr>');
        $('#Name,#Age').val('');
        count++;
    }
</script>
```

This is my Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(List<Student> s)
{
    ViewBag.Items = s.Count; // ALWAYS RETURNS 1
    ViewBad.Value = s[0].Age // TEST VALUE OF FIRST ITEM RETURNS 0
    return View("Index");
}
```

This is my model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCModel.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Form` (HttpPost) API was expected to receive a request body with an array named `s`. You will pass the array as (name) `studentModels` based on your JS code.

```
var Student = "studentModels[" + count + "]";
```

And you miss out on the name attribute for each Age input.

```
<input id="' + Student + '.Age" Age="' + Student + '.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Age + '">
```

---

To fix, make sure the array name in View must be matched with the Controller parameter name. For the below code, I name the array as `s` which is the same as the Controller API expected parameter name.

Also, apply with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and string interpolation to make the HTML string looks clean and easier to bind the values with variables.

```js
function addGenarator() {
    var Name = $('#Name').val();
    var Age = $('#Age').val();
    var Student = "s[" + count + "]";

    var html = `
        <tr>
            <td><input id="${Student}.Name" name="${Student}.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${Name}" /></td>
            <td><input id="${Student}.Age" name="${Student}.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="${Age}" /></td>
        </tr>
    `;
    $('#GenaratorList').append(html);
    $('#Name,#Age').val('');
    count++;
}
```

> Submitted form & Request Form

[image]

> Debugging Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed solution, it was exactly what I was looking for. Could I ask how do I see the debug console on the browser and VS like the ones from your screenshot when I run the application?

Comment: For the debug console in the browser (I used Google Chrome), you can press F12 or right-click Inspect, the Network tab is which captures the incoming response and outgoing request. For VS Studio, you may read [Watch variables with Watch windows and QuickWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I can see the console now ;)